# Extract variables from a sparce distributed representation vector

Tags: statistics, binary

(Familiarity with SDRs , or [space distributed representation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMB0ri4qgwc&list=PL3yXMgtrZmDqhsFQzwUC9V8MeeVOQ7eZ9) will probably help for this question).

*Problem explication :*

Let's say that, at every milliseconds, a sensor measures the 3D coordinates [X,Y,Z] of an ever bouncing ball in a closed room.

At every timestep (1 millisecond), the sensor encodes all 3 coordinate [X,Y,Z] into a **single** binary SDR of size [1000], with 20 "ON bits".

Using only the resulting SDR of the current timestep, there is no way of knowing what were the initial 3 coordinates.

However, our SDRs are guaranteed to have "**semantic**" meaning :in other word, we can take for granted that similar SDRs from different timesteps had similar coordinates.
If we stack these SDRs for a while, we arrive with an SDR vector.

*The problem to solve is the following* :

How, from analysing different "ON BIT" changes or variations in the vector's SDRs, can we get to know which "change / variation" belong to which coordinate ?

In other word, is there a math principle or algorithm that could we re-create 3 SDRs vectors: 
One that would only have "ON bits" for X 
One that would only have "ON bits" for Y 
One that would only have "ON bits" for Z